# Setting source for (Android) MediaPlayer withiout creating a new instance

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Is it possible to set the source (from a file sitting in the **raw** folder).

I know we can do this:

```
    myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tune);
```

But is it actually possible to set this without creating a new instance?

I know there is a few **setDataSource** methods, but I just can't work out how to do this from the ID of a file sitting in my project's RAW folder.

I have tried some suggestions I've seen in other questions, but they just don't seem to work for me.

Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to work with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html):

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I just found this and answered this myself @llya_Gazman, but +1 for the setAudioStreamType which I forgot! Cheers: -)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

So, create the MediaPlayer object once like this:

```
myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Then set the **Raw** resource like so:

```
myPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.name/" + R.raw.filename));
mPlayer.prepare();
```

You'll have to surround the above with try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is here i found after searching for one issue after other in the LogCat

```
MediaPlayer mp;
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_one);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    mp=null;
                }

            });
            mp.start();
```

Not **releasing** the Media player gives you this error in LogCat:

> Android: MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Not **resetting** the Media player gives you this error in LogCat:

> Android: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

So play safe and simple code to use media player.

To **play more than one sounds in same Activity/Fragment** simply change the resID while creating new Media player like

> mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_two);

and play it !

Have fun!